# logging property value in jtl log file

Tags: jmeter

I have been using "sample_variables" to print custom variables in jtl file.
I would also like to print custom parameter using this approach.
But specifying property as -

```
-Jsample_variables=prop1,prop1
```

does not log corresponding value in jtl file. And I see only null values in log file.
Is there a way to log properties in jtl file

UPDATE -

I converted the variable into property using User Parameters and test runs good but yet the variable value is not printed in jtl log. There is always null value printed for sample where variable is used. Test Plan looks as -

[image]

And I added following line to run script -

```
-Jsample_variables=verifytoken \
```

But verifytoken is always null for sample - getTokenInfo
Did I miss any configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert properties to variables using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) functions combination or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function like:

- `${__V(${__P(prop1,)})}`

or

- `${__property(prop1,prop1,)}`

Functions can be called in any place of your JMeter script.

References:

- [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)

Comment: I ended up using User Parameter and stored value of parameter in a variable using ${__property(prop1,prop1,)}

Comment: Updated my question, I yet can not get the variable printed after having converted stored parameter into variable